# Does it really take 15 rep to upvote an answer to your own question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, new-users, privileges

(StackExchange thinks my question is subjective and likely to be closed. =)

I just got this comment "Will upvote you once I get 15 reputation (shame that you can't even upvote an answer to your own question as a newbie...)" on an answer. Is that really true? If so, it's a decidedly odd choice.

Comment: Good point. There's already [a _very_ old post about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/shouldnt-a-rep-less-newbie-at-least-be-able-to-upvote-a-good-answer-to-his-her-o) on meta.SO. However, it doesn't carry the "feature-request" tag ...

Answer (score 11):

Yes it does, and yes, it's odd.

There may be reasons for not allowing low-rep users to upvote each and every question/answer, but they should be able to upvote answers to their own questions. At the very least, accepting an answer should automatically count as upvoting it (which would also do away with zero-score accepted answers).

Comment: Your last point is problematic because of the daily vote limit.

Comment: @Hendrik: It goes without saying that such an "upvote-by-acceptance" should count as upvote with regard to the vote limit. And if one really uses all 30 votes and then proceeds to accept an answer which he/she hadn't upvoted until then ... "Daily voting limit reached, come back in X hours."

Comment: Or maybe even better, the system does it automatically for you on the next day. Why not make it a feature-request? (But maybe it is already "status-declined" over at meta.SO ...)

Comment: But then how would anyone ever get the `Tenacious` and `Unsung Hero` badges!!! =]

Comment: @Adam Noone unless they were redesigned. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you put your game theory hat on, I hope it's easy to see how allowing this would allow massive reputation-based exploits. Anyway, it's sort of intentional that solutions be vetted by a third party who is more objective than the question asker, or even the people answering.

Note that new users *can* accept an answer to their question, which gives them +2 rep and the target user +15 rep.

(and, they can leave comments on their question and all its answers even with 1 rep.)

Comment: If its *"sort of intentional that solutions be vetted by a third party who is more objective than the question asker"*, then why allow anyone *at all* to upvote answers to his/her own questions?

Comment: @lockstep new users are the least trustworthy of all...

Comment: You surely know more about this than I do. `;-)` However, I'd be interested if my "minimum" proposal (upvote-by-acceptance, i.e. one possible upvote per question asked) is also out of the question.

Comment: Actually, I can think of several ways to abuse rep now.